# Unable to display an 'onclick' attribute

Tags: watir-webdriver

I have HTML that looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <a class="xyxyxy" href="" onclick="window.open('https://iogossip.com/Disclosure.pdf', '_blank')">DISCLOSURE</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to put the 'https://iogossip.com/Disclour.pdf' to the screen.  or put the whole thing like "window.open('https://iogossip.com/Disclosure.pdf', '_blank')" to the screen.
when I do this:

```
puts browser.a.onclick
```

I am getting this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `onclick' for #<Watir::Anchor:0x29fc448>
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.2/lib/watir
-webdriver/elements/element.rb:553:in `method_missing'
        from (irb):6
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

thanks,

Comment: It is really unclear what your objective is.  are you trying to simulate the user clicking that link?   When you say 'put to the screen' are you talking about the actual contents of the file, or just the link itself?  Are you trying to inspect or validate what the value of the onclick attribute is?

Comment: I want to capture the link and validate it.  thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can get attribute values using the `Element#attribute_value` method (which should be supported in watir 2.0.3):

```
puts browser.a.attribute_value('onclick')
#=> "window.open('https://iogossip.com/Disclosure.pdf', '_blank')"
```

Answer (score 0):

your code worked fine for me.

try:
    href="#"